# using bootstrap for rails 4 scaffold form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffold

I'm working on styling up my scaffold form page in my rails 4 application and was wondering if anyone had some tips. Is it possible to easily make a [bootstrap form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and change some fields for the `f.select , f.date_field, f.text_field` parts of a scaffolded form?

I was also looking into this gem [formtastic-bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap) which may automatically do what I'm trying to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formtastic and simple_form are great gems, but you don't need them to bootstrap your forms. However, formtastic-bootstrap does make it more convenient to apply bootstrap.

So if you want a quick solution AND a great formbuilder at the same time you could definitively use the gem. If you want to learn bootstrap on the other hand I would recommend to get down and dirty and manually add bootstrap to your forms based on the examples given on getbootstrap.com.